# Find bold words in selection using Office Addin JavaScript API

Tags: office-js

How do you find text in a MS Office Word Addin based on its formatting characteristics?

For instance: find all bold text ranges in my current selection; find all italic text ranges in my current selection; find all capitalised word ranges in my current selection.

```js
Word.run(function (context) {
    var range = context.document.getSelection();
    context.load(range, ['text', 'font']);
    return context.sync()
        .then(function(){
             // This will find me the TEXTUAL words, but not the reference 
             // to the word object so I can operate on it (like change formatting)
             // And it doesn't help me with searching based on <b>bold</b> bits.
             var resultCaps = range.text.match(/(?=[A-Z0-9])([A-Z0-9\s]{2,})/g);
             console.log(resultCaps);
        });
}
```

EDIT: Question updated based on help provided so far...

Searching based on formatting is made harder by some ranges not start with bold text, but contain a bold content.  e.g. "[ **FRED** ]" is ok but "[**FRED**]" is not. (when splitting using getTextRanges())

Is there a way to split each range into individual characters `getTextRanges(???)` and then recombine into words?

For instance:

```js
Word.run(function (context) {
    var words = context.document.getSelection().getTextRanges([' '], true);
    context.load(words, ['text', 'font']);
    var boldRanges = [];
    return context.sync()
        .then(function(){
            for (var i =0; i < words.items.length; ++i) {
                var word = words.items[i];
                if (word.font.bold)
                    boldRanges.push(word);
            }
        })
        .then(function () {
            for (var j = 0; j < boldRanges.length; ++j) {
                boldRanges[j].font.highlightColor = '#FF00FF';
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "word" object, distinct from a Range object. It is the Range object that has formatting properties. One way to get the Range objects that represent the notional words in the selected range, is to use the [Range.getTextRanges()](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/range) method on the Range object that is returned from getSelection. You could pass a space character as the separator character to getTextRanges(). E.g.:

```
var wordRanges = myRange.getTextRanges([' '], true);
```

Then you loop through the wordRanges looking for bolded words with something like this:

```
wordRangesInParagraphs.forEach(function (wordRangesInSingleParagraph) {
   wordRangesInSingleParagraph.items.forEach(function (word, index) {

       // stuffed snipped

        if (word.font.bold) { 
            // do work on the bold words
        }
    }
}
```

This code comes from this file from an Office Add-in sample looks for bolded text, but it's a very long file, so you'll have to search to find where getTextRanges is called and where the result is used.

[Word Add-in JavaScript MarkdownConversion](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-MarkdownConversion/blob/master/Word-Add-in-JavaScript-MDConversionWeb/Home.js)

Comment: Thanks, I can't find `getTextRanges` on `var selection = context.document.getSelection();` object - despite it saying it is there in the docs.

Comment: Ah, it looks like the API VS2015 gave me was outdated!

Comment: I've updated the question, since I've found a case where using a " " delimiter does not work.  Is there a way to split each range into individual characters and then recombine?