# Find subscript/superscript symbols in paragraphs using Office Addin JavaScript API

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

My question is similar to [Find bold words in selection using Office Addin JavaScript API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48371446/find-bold-words-in-selection-using-office-addin-javascript-api)

In my case I have to find **not words** which surrounded by spaces, but alpha-numberic letters in words<sub>like</sub><sup>this</sup> which is formatted as subscript or superscript.
I want to surround them by < sub > and < sup > tags. For example, 404<sup>2</sup> to 404< sup >2< /sup >

There is the equivalent code in python COM:

```
def paragraph_to_html(doc, paragraph):
    rng = doc.Range(paragraph.Range.Start, paragraph.Range.End - 1)
    rng.Find.Text = ''
    rng.Find.Font.Superscript = True
    while rng.Find.Execute():
        rng.InsertBefore('<sup>')
        rng.InsertAfter('</sup>')
        rng.Font.Superscript = False
        rng = doc.Range(rng.End, paragraph.Range.End - 1)
```

I want to rewrite this in Javascript Office Add-In. How to find subscript and superscript letters?

P.S. If it is not possible, how to iterate through every letters in paragraph to check weather its font.subscript==true?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find bold words in selection using Office Addin JavaScript API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48371446/find-bold-words-in-selection-using-office-addin-javascript-api)

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev no, that question is about words, which are surrounded by spaces. In my case subscript letters might be inside words. So the answer to use getTextRanges([' '], true) is not possible.